# Import of test package not possible

Tags: java, testing, directory, package, quarkus

I was trying to import the `io.quarkus.test.*` package into a class in the `src/main` dir of a project. But the IDE always complained about not finding this package even despite the fact it was there (Ctrl+click). Also maven told "cannot find symbol".

But when i moved this java file into the `src/test` dir, the IDE was able to find it and the import could be resolved.

How does this behavior come about? Can someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 2):

To compile any given source file, javac first needs information about all the various types you reference inside it. even `java.lang.String` doesn't mean anything to a java compiler unless it can find the resource `java/lang/String.class`, or possibly if it has a java source file it can compile first, so that it then has a `String.class` file.

Fortunately, just about everywhere java has the 'boot classpath' (or in more modern versions, boot modules) which is where java.lang.String lives. Java knows where this boot location is and automatically includes the lot at all times.

But the rest, such as `io.quarkus.test.stuff`, that has to be either on the classpath, or on a source path, when the compiler runs.

The `src/main` source dir is compiled with various things on the classpath and sourcepath.

**Your `src/test` dir, as well as all dependencies that are configured to be available solely in the test configuration, are not part of that path!**

That's by design: You don't want to ship your unit tests, and therefore there is no need to ship e.g. `junit.jar` and all the other stuff you need solely to run tests, when shipping your app. If your `src/main` code accidentally refers to a file in `src/test` or any test-only dependency and your IDE just hooks it all up as normal, everything works fine on your machine, you ship it to the server (or turn into an installer and ship it to your customers), and then everything fails.

The conclusion is simple:

- If you want access to tooling from the main source tree to stuff that is currently configured for 'test' deployment only, then that is no longer test deployment, and it needs to be moved. Note that the `src/test` dir usually gets access to all the stuff main needs, unless you went out of your way to configure your build in a very weird fashion. So this move will not cause issues in your test code.
- If you have some code in `src/main` that you only really need for testing, it should be in `src/test` instead.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I'd like to suggest to modify the sentence highlighted in bold. Things in `src/test` _are_ compiled with various things on classpath and sourcepath -- the thing is that the classpath and sourcepath are _different_ than in the `src/main` case.

Comment: Heh, what I meant with it, is that `src/test` isn't on the path when compiling src/main. I'll try and think of something that is less confusing.

Comment: seems that every framework provider can classify which part of their packages should be included into this sourcepath. But where does this distinction take place? How does the compiler know, which package to consider as "main" and which not?

Comment: @user3192295 the compiler just does as it is told, specifically, it looks at the `-classpath`, `-sourcepath`, and `-Xbootclasspath` parameters (that last one is automatically set up correctly, don't mess with it), and all source files you give it are inherently also part of it. It's as simple as that. So how does [insert tool you use here] do it? Ask the tool / read docs. example tools: maven, gradle, eclipse, intellij, etc.

Comment: It's likely (though I didn't check) that the Quarkus testing framework is managed by the Quarkus BOM to be `<scope>test</scope>`. If that's the case (again, I think it's very likely, but didn't really check :-) ), then depending on Quarkus testing framework will automatically put it on the _test_ compilation classpath, but not on the _main_ compilation classpath. You can override the `<scope>` manually, but I'd say it's a bad idea in 99% of cases.

Comment: i've looked into the maven local repository, and all jars (main & test) are in the same folder, so as i understand in this case the distinction is made by pom/<scope> of maven as @Ladicek said. That clarifies much for me, thank you very much!